# Adaptively render views in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a RoR app, I have all partial views and a single layout page.  If the request is ajax, I want to return only the partially rendered html, otherwise I want to return the fully rendered html page.

What is the most efficient way to do this in RoR?  I would prefer to do this at the application level rather than in every single controller action.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
if request.xhr?
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html 'element_id', :partial => 'partial_for_ajax'
  end
end
```

In your views just call this controller#action through AJAX and controller will replace your element 'element_id' with partial content.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this means I have to put it in EVERY single controller action.   Is there a way to do it in the base controller? Maybe by overriding the default render method?

Comment: If you need a lot of partial updates, I recommend you to use [Apotomo framework](http://apotomo.de/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how common it is, but with PJAX, im modifying the render method in my application controller:

```
def render(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block)
 if request.headers['X-PJAX'] == 'true'
   options = {} if options.nil?
   options[:layout] = false 
 end
 super(options, extra_options, &block)
```

end

Im not sure, but I would assume you could do the same by checking for request.xhr?